# Datetime Unix timestamp contains milliseconds

Tags: python, unix, datetime

I have a list of unix timestamps that all contain milliseconds -- they are 13 digits long. When I run the timestamp through `datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp)` it returns a `ValueError: Year Out of Range`. When I cut the last three digits off the timestamp and run it through the same format converter, it's works perfectly. Is it possible to run the Unix timestamp that includes milliseconds through the fromtimestamp method of datetime without raising a ValueError? I was looking at the documentation and it didn't say anything about specifying milliseconds.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation, you can see that timestamps in Python are expected to be calculated in seconds, not milliseconds: http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time

You've probably gone over that already.

It should be reasonably easy to slice off the last 3 digits of your timestamps though:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(str(unix_timestamp)[0:-3])
```

You might also wish to do some string length checking to verify that they are 13 digits long instead of just 10 though:

```
if len(unix_timestamp) == 13:
    unix_timestamp = float(str(unix_timestamp)[0:-3])

datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp)
```

By the way, on some systems, timestamps must be between 1970 - 2038. That could also cause a `ValueError`.

If you wish to keep milliseconds, you can store them like this:

```
milliseconds = 0
if len(unix_timestamp) == 13:
    milliseconds = int(unix_timestamp[-3:])
    unix_timestamp = float(unix_timestamp[0:-3])

the_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp)
the_date += timedelta(milliseconds=milliseconds)
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that in the documentation, I just through there might we a way for me to keep the milliseconds and format them. I suppose seconds will suffice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I added in a way you can keep milliseconds as well, if you're looking for that level of precision.

Comment: Did the part `microseconds=milliseconds` not arouse your suspicion? ;)

Comment: Haha, I was looking at one piece of the docs and typed another. Good times with eyeballs.

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly and let me keep the milliseconds. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ChrisClouten: it can't possibly work. `fromtimestamp()` expects a number, not string. [Just try it](http://ideone.com/PzeyWd).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian converted to a float, just to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

The `fromtimestamp` method expects a unix timestamp and that has a resolution of seconds. You will have to convert your time in two steps:

```
mytime = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp/1000)
                 .replace(microsecond = (timestamp % 1000) * 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Explanation by @Jordan is very nice but i think there might be error in parsing which i was facing so i coorected the code as below:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(str(timestamp)[0:-3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply divide the time stamp value by 1000.

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp/1000.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `unix_timestamp_millis` contains "milliseconds since epoch" and you want to get the local time using `datetime.fromtimestamp()` method (a variation on [@Chronial's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18724165/4279)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

seconds, millis = divmod(unix_timestamp_millis, 1000)
local_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds).replace(microsecond=millis*1000)
```

To take into account possible changes in the local timezone rules over time, you could use [the tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html) via `pytz` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = get_localzone() # get pytz tzinfo object   
seconds, millis = divmod(unix_timestamp_millis, 1000)
local_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds, local_timezone)
local_dt = local_dt.replace(microsecond=millis*1000)
```

The result is a timezone-aware datetime object.

If you can't install 3rd party modules then use UTC time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

seconds, millis = divmod(unix_timestamp_millis, 1000)
utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds).replace(microsecond=millis*1000)
```

---

If input is a [POSIX timestamp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_15) given as a number of milliseconds (likely; unless "right" timezone is used) then you could find the broken-down UTC time via direct formula:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

utc_dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=unix_timestamp_millis)
```